# How to put a image in div that image is larger than div?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi i have a div as like that

---

This is Frame a div

[image]

---

This is my images

[image]

---

[image]
This is result

The images width and height is not fixed because i don't know what is size images

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write like this:

**CSS**

```
div{
    border:5px solid red;
    display:inline-block;
    box-shadow:0 0 0 10px green;
    margin:100px;
}
img{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWutL.jpg"></div>​
```

​

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/QkT7d/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the image width/height depending on a percentage of the `div`:

```
div img
{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/x83dk/